# Незапускается поиск Bluetooth устройств

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, xamarin.forms

Пишу кроссплатформенную реализацию поиска BLE устройств. Имею следующий код обертки над стандартным UWP классом:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BtTest.UWP.Models.BluetoothScaner))]
namespace BtTest.UWP.Models
{
public class BluetoothScaner : IBluetoothScaner
{
    public BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher Watcher { get; set; }

    public BluetoothScaner()
    {
        Watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher()
        {
            ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active
        };
        Watcher.Received += OnRecieved;
        Watcher.Stopped += WatcherStopped;
        Watcher.Start();
    }

    private void WatcherStopped(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender,
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs args)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void OnRecieved(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender,
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Received?.Invoke(args.Advertisement.LocalName, args);
        Console.WriteLine("onRecieved");
    }

    public event Action<string, object> Received;

    public void Start()
    {
        Watcher.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Watcher.Stop();
    }
}
}
```

Использую его следующим образом в проекте реализации UWP

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private MainPageModel _mainPageModel;
    private IBluetoothScaner _bluetoothScaner = DependencyService.Get<IBluetoothScaner>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListViewBtItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private void OnDeviceDetected(string name, object bluetoothArgs)
    {
        Add(name, bluetoothArgs);
    }

    public void Add(string name, object bluetoothArgs)
    {
        _mainPageModel.DeviceDict.Add(name, bluetoothArgs);
        ListViewBtItems.Add(name);
    }

    public object GetValue(string name)
    {
        return _mainPageModel.DeviceDict[name];
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        _bluetoothScaner.Received += OnDeviceDetected;

        _bluetoothScaner.Start();
    }
}
```

В итоге получаю, что событие OnRecieved никогда не срабатывает, хотя должно и устройства в эфире есть.
Что интересно - строчка Watcher.Start(); переводит объект Watcher в состояние Aborted, а не Started. Это было установленно через дебагер. Может ли кто нибудь помочь разобраться в данной проблеме?

Comment: А для чего два раза Start() вызывать? Один раз в конструкторе и второй раз явно методом?

Comment: Да, можно один раз. Но на результате это не отражается

Comment: Не можно, а нужно. далее, глянуть, дергается ли Stopped событие. Если да, то там будет код ошибки. Ну и вообще, работает ли скан в другом коде (в той же демки от MS). Можно реализовать через прямой вызов WinRT через интерфейсы, тогда можно увидеть код ошибки, возвращаемой Start()/

Comment: Stopped дергается. Код BluetoothScaner работает на WinForm приложении. Там я вручную добавлял 
Windows.winmd
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

Comment: И какой код ошибки в Stopped?

Comment: ошибка DisabledByUser https://ibb.co/WzX4MXL

Comment: Ну что там MS имела в виду под данным кодом не совсем понятно, но вроде как недостаточно прав у приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена благодаря комментариям Mike Petrichenko и статье https://keyoti.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-in-windows-10-troubleshooting-capabilities/
Всем спасибо